# What OOP in Javascript should look like?

Tags: javascript, oop

I was writing a longish piece of code using Jquery and as you all know, what it seemed to be a simple project, when growing in complexity, now is looking like an unmanageable spaghetti with functions and code repeated everywhere. Therefore, I started pouring all the functionality over an objects like this:

```
function MyObject(container) {
    this.container = container
};

Notifications.prototype.featureOne = function (arg1, arg2){

};

Notifications.prototype.featureTwo = function (arg1, arg2, arg3){

};

obj1 = new Notifications($('#container'));
obj1.featureOne('arg1', 'arg2');
obj1.featureOne('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3');
```

Obviously, that makes it very simple to know what is going on but I noticed I had some code very similar to another (particularly, an ajax function accepting 2 arguments and another ajax function accepting the same 2 arguments than before plus an additional one). What can I do? Create a new prototype method to create a function to wrap both cases there?.

Another question: What are best practices that you use when dealing with OOP in Javascript?.

Thanks!

Comment: If you'd like to see some proper code, go to http://coffeescript.org -> "Try CoffeeScript" and type `class Foo \n\n class Bar extends Foo` (replace \n with linebreaks) - but it'll probably be a bit hard to understand.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know CoffeeScript, so for now that woudn't help me too much.

Answer (score 1):

Prototypical inheritance works like this. Say you have a "class".

```
// original "class"
var SomeObject = function( constructorArg1 ) {
   this.someProperty = constructorArg1;
};
SomeObject.prototype.method1 = function( arg1, arg2 ) {
   // some code
};
```

Now let's say you want to create a class that inherits method1, but also adds more.

```
// new "class" which inherits from first "class"
var SomeOtherObject = function( constructorArg1 ) {
   this.someProperty = constructorArg1;
};
// inheritance happens here
SomeOtherObject.prototype = new SomeObject();
// must also set the constructor as part of prototypical inheritance
SomeOtherObject.prototype.constructor = SomeOtherObject;
// add a second method to your new "class"
SomeOtherObject.prototype.method2 = function( arg1 ) {
   // some code
};
```

You will see that the system isn't perfect, as it doesn't let you inherit the original constructor, and you cannot call parent class methods if they are overwritten, but all methods added to the prototype of the first "class" are now available in the new "class".

There are about 100 ways you can play with this idea to simulate classical inheritance, and pretty much set it up how you want it to work, with being able to call overwritten parent methods from within the extended class etc. Many methods that simulate classical inheritance don't use the prototypical inheritance at all, and instead just simply copy methods from one prototype to another. You will have to do some searching or experimenting to see what works best for you.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SomeOtherObject.prototype.constructor = SomeOtherObject;`